# Truffle: how to override compiler settings via the CLI?

Tags: truffle, coverage

This is a highly specific bottleneck encountered when using Truffle.

1. In my normal `truffle-config.js` file, I have the optimizer enabled.
2. I run a CI pipeline which has a coverage job.
3. I use [0x/sol-coverage](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-monorepo/tree/development/packages/sol-coverage) and it seems that when enabling the Solidity optimizer some information about the source code is lost and the aggregate coverage is lower than it should be.
4. Therefore, I would ideally be able to run `truffle compile --disable-optimizer` - or some way to modify the compiler settings.

At worst, I could modify the `truffle-config.js` file before running the coverage job, but I feel this is not good practice.

Are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to checking for some environment variables in the `truffle-config.js` file, although I'm not fully satisfied by this solution. I'll keep this thread open until I find a better alternative.